# How to add 2 different datasources to a single gridview in different columns?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 2 datasources that i want to put in 2 different columns, how do you add 2 datasources to 2 different columns?

```
        List<string> credits = new List<string>();
        List<string> status = new List<string>();

       /missing code shitty limits

            foreach(DataRow dataRow in dt.Rows) //Checks the server if it is running or not.
            {
                string value = dataRow.Field<string>("Slave_IO_Running"); //Looks for "Slave_IO_Running" status.

                if (value == "Yes")
                {                     
                    status.Add(Name + ": Working");
                    credits.Add(credentials);

                }
                else
                {
                    status.Add(Name  + ": Replication ERR");
                }
                break;
            }
            GridView1.DataSource = credits;
            GridView1.DataSource = status;
            GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: You cannot. You have to merge the sources and bind the data.

Comment: I can bind the data easy, status.Add(Name + credentials + ": Replication ERR"); but then they are both in 1 column?